# login and download files from ftp site

Tags: c#, .net, ftp

I am trying to download some files via an FTP site. However the code keeps debugging on the last line of code shown below. It tells me that it can't login to the FTP site. I have however logged into the site manually with the same password and username I'm using in my code. Can't see what I'm doing wrong?

```
string HOST = @"ftp://indexftp.barcap.com/point/download";
string PASSWORD = "password";
string USERNAME = "username";

FtpWebRequest ftpRequest = (FtpWebRequest)FtpWebRequest.Create(HOST + fileName);
            ftpRequest.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(USERNAME, PASSWORD);

            ftpRequest.UseBinary = true;
            ftpRequest.UsePassive = true;
            ftpRequest.KeepAlive = true;
            ftpRequest.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.DownloadFile;               
            FtpWebResponse ftpResponse = (FtpWebResponse)ftpRequest.GetResponse();
```

**The error message**

The remote server return an error (530) Not logged in

Comment: It would really help if you shared the exact error. "It tells me that it can't login to the FTP site"...but why? Is it saying network path not found? Invalid login details? Cannot connect? The actually error would help diagnose the problem better

Comment: Show us your setup of the "manual" login.

Comment: for my manual login. I copy the HOST string into my internet explorer. I am then prompted to enter my user name & password. I copy the username & password from my code above, press enter and it lets me in & I can see the files I wish to download

Comment: Sorry my answer didn't help OP. I'm still figuring out SO n_n'